# How to style the arrow that opens submenus in jQuery mmenu?

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

does anyone know how the arrow in mmenu that opens (vertical) submenus is generated and how i can possibly style it via css? Any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

[Link to mmenu website](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl)

Comment: Arrows are generated using CSS3 transform property. It's basically a block element with two grey borders (bottom & left) that is rotated 45 deg. There are visual tools to help you with creating a transform matrix. Read: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

Comment: Thanks, that made it clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css styles for these arrows are the following ones:

```
.mm-prev:before, .mm-next:after, .mm-arrow:after {
    content: '';
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

if you apply this css to an anchor, you will have a 45 degree rotated box with a 2 pixel border line. Then you can remove the border of each sides you want like the following code to have a right sided arrow:

```
.mm-next:after, .mm-arrow:after {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    right: 20px;
}
```

and below code to have a left sided arrow:

```
.mm-next:after, .mm-arrow:after {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in detail to me!